# Side-by-side diff highlights unchanged word following formatting marks

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff

When someone makes a small formatting change, e.g. italicizing a phrase with asterisks, the *unchanged* word immediately following it is struck out and highlighted as a difference.

The third paragraph in this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10667920) demonstrates the issue. The words "object" and "methods" are highlighted even though they were not changed.

Here's a simulation with bold standing in for the highlighting.

> Do you **<strike>really want</strike>** to do this? ... Do you ***really* want** to do this?

The word "want" should not be highlighted as changed.

> Do you **<strike>really</strike>** want to do this? ... Do you ***really*** want to do this?

Comment: What you're saying and what's going on in the linked edit don't match up for me :/

Comment: @Will What David is saying is that the words "object" and "method" are highlighted in the edit, even though they were never touched by the editor. I noticed the same thing about my own edits, but I didn't think of posting here.

Comment: I'd have posted this as a [feature-request], not as a [bug] though.

Comment: Thanks, @MrLister, I've updated the question to point out the words.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256174/improve-display-of-suggested-edit-deltas-for-format-changes

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now; see [Improve display of suggested edit deltas for format changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256174/improve-display-of-suggested-edit-deltas-for-format-changes/291341#291341) on Meta.SE.